# Smooth torus eversion

Tags: geometry, homotopy-theory

I asked a vague question about torus eversion earlier, with no hard math, so while I'm at it, how about this one, which may involve hard math:

"Everybody knows" that Stephen Smale showed us how to evert a sphere without tearing or creasing:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_w4HYXuo9M

Has anyone done the same with a torus?

Comment: Do you mean *invert* a sphere?

Comment: [sphere eversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphereEversion.html)

Comment: @DanielRust No entry at [Cambride Dictionaires](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/british/?q=evert) for *evert*. Thanks.

Comment: I was just wondering this the other day. Here's the related video.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQcy5DvpvlM

Comment: @GitGud : No.  I meant "evert".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kQcy5DvpvlM) seems to suggest the answer is yes. Séquin goes in to some detail in [this document](http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/sambusetti/geometria/torusimmersions.pdf) and I'll add the image he references, made by [Cheritat](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~cheritat/lab/e_labo.html).

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful picture. My father (Derek Hacon; a student of Zeeman) had shown me the same picture when I was a kid. He also observed that this gives a sphere eversion. Just push the south pole upwards, past the equator, then a cross section looks like two circles (just as with the torus; but you have to glue two disks and an annulus instead of two annuli). Then follow the above sequence of cross-sections.
I believe he tried to publish it in some expository / general audience journal, but it was rejected as too elementary.